# The value of the local variable is not used

Tags: java, int, java-7

all of the variables above have the warning in the title. Could you please tell me why that is happening?

```
public class DataTypes {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        // new feature in JDK 7
        int x = 0b1010; // 12
        int y = 0b1010_1010;
        int ssn = 444_12_7691;
        long phone = 408_777_6666L;
        double num = 9_632_401_909.1_0_3;
        String twoLine = "line one\nline two";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, per se, however, the compiler is warning you that you aren't really doing anything. You are taking values and assigning them to a group of variables and that is it. You are doing nothing with that data.

Answer (score 5):

The variables you declared are never used, only assigned to, therefore you're being warned.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the variables: `x`, `y`, `ssn`, `phone`, `num` and `twoLine`.
But you never use the variables anywhere in the code.
For instance, if you print the variables out:

```
System.out.println(x + y + ssn + phone + num + twoLine);
```

All the warnings should disappear